# Is it possible to pass an unknown amount of variables, via a single variable, into a function call that uses args and kwargs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to pass an unknown amount of variables, via a single variable, into a function call?

The issue I am having is that I am iterating over a dataframe and each row will use a bitstring `pack` function call - each call might have a different number of arguments depending on the length of a list in
`row['Data']`

```
for index, row in log_file.iterrows():
    pack_string = 'u1u11u1u1u1u4{}'.format('u8'*len(row['Data']))
    packed = bitstruct.pack(pack_string, 0, row['ID'], 0, 0, 0, len(row['Data']),)
```

Examples of pack_string might look like this:

```
u1u11u1u1u1u4u8u8u8
u1u11u1u1u1u4u8u8u8u8u8u8
u1u11u1u1u1u4u8u8
u1u11u1u1u1u4u8u8u8u8u8u8u8u8
```

For every u8 I need to pass a new variable into the `bitstruct.pack()` method. So for a single loop on the pack_string `u1u11u1u1u1u4u8u8` the solution would be:

```
pack_string = 'u1u11u1u1u1u4{}'.format('u8'*len(row['Data']))
packed = bitstruct.pack(pack_string, 0, row['ID'], 0, 0, 0, len(row['Data']), row['Data'][0], row['Data'][1])
```

An ideal solution for a chaning number of parameters might look something like this:

```
for index, row in log_file.iterrows():
    pack_string = 'u1u11u1u1u1u4{}'.format('u8'*len(row['Data']))
    *args = row['Data']
    packed = bitstruct.pack(pack_string, 0, row['ID'], 0, 0, 0, len(row['Data']), *args)
```

Comment: You can pass `*row['Data']`

Comment: You're quite close - it should be `args = row['Data']` the way you're doing it, and you don't need a temporary like that (you can use `*row['Data']` directly in the function call).

Comment: If either of you would like to submit and answer, I would happily accept it. Thank you both!

Comment: I've closed the question, but you can still accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack am arbitrary iterable into individual arguments using the "splat" operator:

```
for index, row in log_file.iterrows():
    pack_string = 'u1u11u1u1u1u4{}'.format('u8'*len(row['Data']))
    packed = bitstruct.pack(pack_string, 0, row['ID'], 0, 0, 0, len(row['Data']), *row['Data'])
```

The only issue with your last attempt is that  `*args = row['Data']` should have been just

```
args = row['Data']
```